# running two threads simultaneously inside a stateless agent and guaranting communication between them

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, agent

I am developing a **stateless** Agent in **Java** that takes informations from one Server and transfer it to another client. It means that the agent is located between a client and a server. So I am thinking to run two threads **simultaneously** on the agent: one thread (thread1) runs a serverSocket and get request from client while another threads (thread2)is runnning and makes communication with the server. The problem consists in synchronizing between the two threads. I am thinking in making thread 1 asking whole the time thread 2 about a new Information. If thread 2 has nothing new, he will not answer it. What is the best way to synchronize between them. Should I use a global variable (a flag) to synchronize between them? Can I save Information when I have a stateless agent?

Comment: This is a very broad question, but I suggest you look at [java.util.concurrent.Exchanger<V>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html) and see if that gets you even part way there, then ask more specific (and answerable) questions as you encounter them.

Comment: it is more about concept. Then I will decide depending on technology, how to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should modify your app into **async model**.

Your app needs:
 - an entry point to accept incoming connections -> a good example is an async servlet (or one dedicated thread).
 - a ThreadPoolExecutor that provides fixed numbers of workers and a blocking queue (use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor(int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue)) constructor).

**The workflow:**

1. Accept incomming request.
2. Wrapp incoming request into (Runnable) task.
3. Put task into blocking queue.
4. If ThreadPoolExecutor has a free worker starts processing the task

**An advantage** of such a model is that you are able to **handle one request using one thread**. So there is no need to manually synchronize anything.

Comment: When these workers finish processing their task, how and who should send the result to agent. ?

Comment: @amitakCs If you pass a specific "response object" as one of parameters to your (Runnable) task then the worker should be able to answer to the agent. In case of Servlet that "response object" is ServletResponse object.